# Spark dataframe explode column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

Every row in the dataframe contains a csv formatted string `line` plus another simple string, so what I'm trying to get at the end is a dataframe composed of the fields extracted from the `line` string together with `category`.
So I proceeded as follows to explode the `line` string

```
val df = stream.toDF("line","category")
.map(x => x.getString(0))......
```

At the end I manage to get a new dataframe composed of the line fields but I can't return the `category` to the new dataframe 
I can't join the new dataframe with the initial one since the common field `id` was not a separate column at first.

Sample of input :

```
line                           | category 
"'1';'daniel';'dan@gmail.com'" | "premium"
```

Sample of output:

```
id  | name    | email          | category
1   | "daniel"| "dan@gmail.com"| "premium"
```

Any suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post sample of input dataframe and expected dataframe?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan i edited the question, take a look

Comment: are the line column always id, name and email combined?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan yes always  that structure

Comment: I have answered it below :) hope its helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the structure of strings in `line` column is fixed as mentioned in the question, then following simple solution should work where `split` inbuilt function is used to split the string into array and then finally selecting the elements from the array and aliasing to get the final dataframe

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("line", split(col("line"), ";"))
  .select(col("line")(0).as("id"), col("line")(1).as("name"), col("line")(2).as("email"), col("category"))
  .show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+--------+---------------+--------+
|id |name    |email          |category|
+---+--------+---------------+--------+
|'1'|'daniel'|'dan@gmail.com'|premium |
+---+--------+---------------+--------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful